# Swift and Sprite Kit - How can I measure the total distance a sprite has travelled?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

In my game, the player sprite travels continiously upwards as I have set the velocity of the sprite in the update function with:

```
override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
...

  player.physicsBody!.velocity.dy = max(player.physicsBody!.velocity.dy, 650 * gameGain)

}
```

Now I would like to measure the total distance the sprite has travelled. Is there any way/method to do so or do I have to make a variable to manually count the distance, e.g.

```
var distance:Float
override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {


  player.physicsBody!.velocity.dy = max(player.physicsBody!.velocity.dy, 650 * gameGain)

  distance += 650

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: keep track of your starting location and just use the distance formula

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in the distance from the starting location to the current location, you can remember the start location and then calculate the distance:

```
let startPosition: CGPoint
var distance: CGFloat

init(startLocation: CGPoint) {
    self.startPosition = startPosition
    distance = 0
}

// Calculate the distance between two points using Pythagoras. You can make your code clean, by moving this into an extension for CGPoint.
private func distance(point1: CGPoint, point1: CGPoint) -> CGFloat {
    let dx = point1.x - point2.x
    let dy = point1.y - point2.y
    return sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
}

override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    // Move the sprite
    let newPlayerPosition = player.position
    distance = distance(point1: newPlayerPosition, point2: startPosition)
}
```